# Object values not showing up in ejs

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm creating a blog and trying to make a page that lists the title of each article I've written. Example:

```
List of Articles:
 * Title: Article 1
 * Title: Article 2
 * Title: Article 3
```

Here's my Schema

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Here's the code that sorts and renders each article to the ejs page.

```
exports.article_list = function (req, res, next) {
  Article.find({}, "title author")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .populate("author")
    .exec(function (err, list_articles) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      //Successful, so render
      res.render("article_list", {
        title: "Article List",
        article_list: list_articles,
      });
    });
};
```

And here is the code in my ejs page.

```
  <ul>
    <% article_list.forEach(function() { %>
    <li>Title:<%= article_list.title %></li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
```

The code seems to work because I have three test articles saved in my MongoDB database and three `list items` show up on the page but they're blank so I'm assuming they're showing up as undefined for some reason. When I have just

```
<%= article_list %>
```

in my ejs page, it shows each object with the correct vales but in JSON format.

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("641bf67f339b048733c05d2d"), title: 'First article', author: 'test' },
{ _id: new ObjectId("641d311570a689a1bf2a4c5d"), title: 'Second article', author: 'test' },
{ _id: new ObjectId("643252040d73d534661040b5"), title: 'Third article', author: 'test' }
```

I'm having issues getting it to display the way I want it which is just the title of the article. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function should take an argument (for example can write something like `article` in your case) which means the current item in the `article_list` array
Then inside you can access the articles properties by `article.propertyName`

```js
<ul>
    <% article_list.forEach(function(article) { %>
    <li>Title:<%= article.title %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```